# Using GridSearchCV for RandomForestRegressor

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, cross-validation

I'm trying to use `GridSearchCV` for `RandomForestRegressor`, but always get `ValueError: Found array with dim 100. Expected 500`. Consider this toy example:

```py
import numpy as np

from sklearn import ensemble
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

if __name__ == '__main__':

    X = np.random.rand(1000, 2)
    y = np.random.rand(1000)

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
        X, y, test_size=0.5, random_state=1)

    # Set the parameters by cross-validation
    tuned_parameters = {'n_estimators': [500, 700, 1000], 'max_depth': [None, 1, 2, 3], 'min_samples_split': [1, 2, 3]}

    # clf = ensemble.RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=500, n_jobs=1, verbose=1)
    clf = GridSearchCV(ensemble.RandomForestRegressor(), tuned_parameters, cv=5, scoring=r2_score, n_jobs=-1, verbose=1)
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    print clf.best_estimator_
```

This is what I get:

```py
Fitting 5 folds for each of 36 candidates, totalling 180 fits
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\abudis\Dropbox\machine_learning\toy_example.py", line 21, in <module>
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
  File "C:\Users\abudis\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\sklearn\grid_search.py", line 596, in fit
    return self._fit(X, y, ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
  File "C:\Users\abudis\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\sklearn\grid_search.py", line 378, in _fit
    for parameters in parameter_iterable
  File "C:\Users\abudis\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 653, in __call__
    self.dispatch(function, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\abudis\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 400, in dispatch
    job = ImmediateApply(func, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\abudis\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 138, in __init__
    self.results = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\abudis\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.py", line 1240, in _fit_and_score
    test_score = _score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorer)
  File "C:\Users\abudis\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.py", line 1296, in _score
    score = scorer(estimator, X_test, y_test)
  File "C:\Users\abudis\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\metrics.py", line 2324, in r2_score
    y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_reg_targets(y_true, y_pred)
  File "C:\Users\abudis\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\metrics.py", line 65, in _check_reg_targets
    y_true, y_pred = check_arrays(y_true, y_pred)
  File "C:\Users\abudis\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 254, in check_arrays
    % (size, n_samples))
ValueError: Found array with dim 100. Expected 500
```

For some reason `GridSearchCV` thinks that `n_estimators` parameter should be equal to the size of each fold. If I change the first value of the `n_estimators` in the tuned_parameters list I get `ValueError` with another expected value.

Training just one model using `clf = ensemble.RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=500, n_jobs=1, verbose=1)` works fine though, so not sure if I'm doing something wrong or there's a bug in `scikit-learn` somewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like a bug, but in your case it should work if you use `RandomForestRegressor`'s own scorer (which coincidentally is R^2 score) by not specifying any scoring function in `GridSearchCV`:

```
clf = GridSearchCV(ensemble.RandomForestRegressor(), tuned_parameters, cv=5, 
                   n_jobs=-1, verbose=1)
```

EDIT: As mentioned by @jnothman in [#4081](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4081) this is the real problem:

> scoring does not accept a metric function. It accepts a function of signature (estimator, > X, y_true=None) -> float score. You can use scoring='r2' or scoring=make_scorer(r2_score).

Comment: I have created two issues [#4080](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4080) and [#4081](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4081).

Comment: Ah, okay. Yeah, I specified the scoring parameter because I didn't really know what the default was for regressors (mse or r2). Removing it altogether did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use all regression scoring in "[[https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html]](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html)"

This is a example code for MSE:

```
cv=RepeatedKFold(n_splits=10,n_repeats=3, random_state=100)



pipeRF = Pipeline([('classifier', [RandomForestRegressor()])]) 

param_grid = [{'classifier' : [RandomForestRegressor()],'classifier__n_estimators': [100, 200],'classifier__min_samples_split': [8, 10],'classifier__min_samples_leaf': [3, 4, 5],'classifier__max_depth': [80, 90]}]




clf = GridSearchCV(pipeRF, param_grid = param_grid, cv = cv, n_jobs=-1, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')
```

For r2 use:

```
clf = GridSearchCV(pipeRF, param_grid = param_grid, cv = cv, n_jobs=-1, scoring='r2')
```